# Routing with argument and Popup not working at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

arguments not going to next page, but if I stop dialog then it's going.

Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.CATEGORYSCREEN, arguments: "buying");
myResultDialog();

Comment: if you are using getx consider including  the tag, also provide snippet that will reproduce the same issue .

Comment: Yes, I am using GetX. What is solution?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know about getx, others may help